# serving static files with restify (node.js)

Tags: node.js, http, restify

I have the following code:

app.js

```
[...]

server.get(/\/docs\/public\/?.*/, restify.serveStatic({
  directory: './public'
}));

server.listen(1337, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

And I have the following file structure

```
app.js
public/
  index.html
```

So I try browsing:

```
http://localhost:1337/docs/public/index.html
```

and I get

```
{
  code: "ResourceNotFound",
  message: "/docs/public/index.html"
}
```

I tried with several variations, but none of them seemed to work.

I'm sure it should be something pretty obvious I'm missing

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`restify` will use the `directory` option as a prefix for *the entire route path*. In your case, it will look for `./public/docs/public/index.html`.

Comment: I'm finding restify to be terribly documented.

Answer (score 8):

1. The `directory` option is a prefix for your entire path.
2. Relative paths are not working correctly in later versions of Restify (I tested 2.6.0-3, 2.8.2-3 - and they all produce the NotAuthorized error)

The solution now becomes:

```
server.get(/\/docs\/public\/?.*/, restify.serveStatic({
    directory: __dirname
}));
```

And then your static files will need to be in `./docs/public`.
(`__dirname` is a global variable that contains the absolute path of the script you are running)

Comment: This did it for me!! The `__dirname` option is the key!

Comment: There appears to be a bug for OSX that prevents using ./ syntax, so this was the only thing that worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Based on @NdeeJim's answer, to anyone wondering how to serve ALL the static resources:

```
server.get(/\/?.*/, restify.plugins.serveStatic({
            directory: __dirname,
            default: 'index.html',
            match: /^((?!app.js).)*$/   // we should deny access to the application source
     }));
```