# Serving static files with restify

Tags: node.js, restify

I am learning to use Node.js. Currently, I have a folder structure that looks like the following:

```
index.html
server.js
client
  index.html
  subs
    index.html
    page.html
res
  css
    style.css
  img
    profile.png
  js
    page.js
    jquery.min.js
```

server.js is my webserver code. I run this from a command-line using `node server.js`. The contents of that file are:

```
var restify = require('restify');

var server = restify.createServer({
    name: 'Test App',
    version: '1.0.0'
});

server.use(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());

server.get('/echo/:name', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send(req.params);
    return next();
});

server.listen(2000, function () {
    console.log('%s running on %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

As you can see, this server relies on RESTIFY. I've been told I must use RESTIFY. However, I can't figure out how to serve static files. For instance, how do I server the *.html, *.css, *.png, and *.js files in my app?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463841/serving-static-files-with-restify-node-js?rq=1

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://restify.com/docs/plugins-api/#servestatic):

```
server.get(/\/docs\/public\/?.*/, restify.plugins.serveStatic({
  directory: './public'
}));
```

But this will search files in the `./public/docs/public/` directory.
If you want to not append request path to it, use `appendRequestPath: false` option.

I prefer to use [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) key here:

```
server.get(/\/public\/?.*/, restify.plugins.serveStatic({
    directory: __dirname 
}));
```

*The value of `__dirname` is equal to script file directory path, which assumed to be also a folder, where is `public` directory.*

And now we map all `/public/.*` urls to `./public/` directory.

---

Now also exists [serveStaticFiles](http://restify.com/docs/plugins-api/#servestaticfiles) plugin:

```
server.get('/public/*', // don't forget the `/*`
     restify.plugins.serveStaticFiles('./doc/v1')
); // GET /public/index.html -> ./doc/v1/index.html file
```

Comment: Which value would `__dirname` have in your case?

Answer (score 10):

According to my current restify version **(v5.2.0)**

the `serveStatic` has been moved into `plugins`, so the code would be like this

```
server.get(
  /\/(.*)?.*/,
  restify.plugins.serveStatic({
    directory: './static',
  })
)
```

Syntax above will serve your static files on folder `static`. So you can get the static file like `http://yoursite.com/awesome-photo.jpg`

For some reason if you want to serve the static files under specific path like this `http://yoursite.com/assets/awesome-photo.jpg` for example.

The code should be refactored into this

```
server.get(
  /\/assets\/(.*)?.*/,
  restify.plugins.serveStatic({
    directory: `${app_root}/static`,
    appendRequestPath: false
  })
)
```

The option `appendRequestPath: false` above means we dont include `assets` path into the file name

Answer (score 8):

From Restify 7 the routes [no longer take full regexes](http://restify.com/docs/6to7/), so if you want `/public/stylesheet.css` to serve the file `./public/stylesheet.css`, your code would now look like this:

```
server.get('/public/*', restify.plugins.serveStatic({
  directory: __dirname,
}))
```

This is because Restify 7 has a new (potentially faster) routing back-end: [find-my-way](https://github.com/delvedor/find-my-way)

Answer (score 2):

this is how i'm serving static files in restify

```
server.get(/\/public\/docs\/?.*/, restify.plugins.serveStatic({

          directory: __dirname,

          default: 'index.html'

        }));
```

public access path will be :  example.com/public/docs/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue just recently, so while this may not help you it could help others who are having trouble with it.

When you declare Restify as `const restify = require('restify');`, the serveStatic method will be in the plugins object so using `restify.serveStatic` will quietly fail. The correct way to access the method is `restify.plugins.serveStatic`.

You can find the update docs here: http://restify.com/docs/plugins-api/#serve-static

Answer (score 1):

```
server.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
            return;
        }
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
        next();
    });
});
```

Comment: How do you import fs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Here view is a static resource directory name

```
server.get('/\/.*/', restify.plugins.serveStatic({

    directory: __dirname + "/view/",
    default: './home.html' 

   })
);
```